# Can Windows Blender load a project from a WSL2 filesystem file?

Tags: windows, file-browser

Windows can access WSL2 paths as `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\me\scene.blend` but I can't type that path into blender's File>Open dialog box (2.93 alpha nightly of 2021-01-18) to load my project into Blender running on windows. Is there another way to load projects from a WSL2 distro (or otherwise use weird NTFS path names like this) into Windows blender? (Other than copying the .blend file to Windows filesystem of course)

Comment: I thought Symlinks might provide a workable solution.  Related SU post - https://superuser.com/questions/1391662/sane-symlinks-to-parallelize-windows-and-ubuntu-homes-on-wsl

Comment: @AllenSimpson that works great, thanks for the idea! If you convert that to an answer I'll accept it. Specifically, in a cmd.exe window: `mklink /d c:\wsl2-home \\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\me` and then open `c:/wsl2-home/scene.blend` in blender.

Comment: since you did all the work I'd just post and accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended by @AllenSimpson, the simplest answer is to create a Windows symlink:
`mklink /d c:\wsl2-home \\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\me` and then in Blender you can open `c:/wsl2-home/scene.blend` as usual.